# Type '{ refetch: any; }' is missing using Formik and React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik

I get the following error when i try to pass a prop down to my EmailSignupScreen. I am trying out Formik with Typescript

**"message": "Type '{ refetch: any; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly**

I have already added in refetch as a FormProps in my EmailSignupScreen.tsx and have also type it as any. Hence, my EmailSignupScreen should be expecting a refetch prop which I have passed down from my Routes.tsx file

Routes.tsx

```
<Route
  path="/signup"
  render={() => <EmailSignupScreen refetch={refetch} />}
/>
```

EmailSignupScreen.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import { withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from "react-router";
// import { Mutation } from "react-apollo";
import {
  Formik,
  FormikProps,
  FormikActions,
  Form,
  Field,
  FieldProps,
  InjectedFormikProps
} from "formik";
// import { ADD_COMMENT } from "src/graphql/mutations";

interface MyFormValues {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

interface FormProps extends RouteComponentProps<any> {
  refetch: any;
}

export const EmailSignup: React.SFC<
  InjectedFormikProps<FormProps, MyFormValues>
> = ({ refetch }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Formik Form</h1>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
        onSubmit={(
          values: MyFormValues,
          actions: FormikActions<MyFormValues>
        ) => {
          console.log({ values, actions });
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          actions.setSubmitting(false);
        }}
        render={(formikBag: FormikProps<MyFormValues>) => (
          <Form>
            <Field
              name="email"
              render={({ field, form }: FieldProps<MyFormValues>) => (
                <div>
                  <input type="text" {...field} placeholder="Email" />
                  {form.touched.email && form.errors.email && form.errors.email}
                </div>
              )}
            />
          </Form>
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const EmailSignupScreen = withRouter(EmailSignup);

export { EmailSignupScreen };
```

Answer (score 0):

i resolved the issue by adding 'any &' before 'FormikProps & FormProps'. not sure if this is the correct way though. feel free to suggest if there is a better way. thanks

btw, anyone know y adding 'any &' before FormikProps<... works?

```
export const EmailSignup: React.SFC<
  any & FormikProps<FormValues> & FormProps
> = props => { return ( ...
```